# Should I stop using GSS etc. if I want to be ready for GWT 3?

Tags: gwt, gwt-jsinterop, gss

I've ditched GWT Widgets in favor of JsInterop and Elemental2.

But I'm still using modules from "gwt-user.jar" for **GSS, Resources, and I18N**.

Are these modules likely to be supported in the next version of GWT? If not, is there a future-friendly alternative that I can use?

I'm just starting out, so I'd rather get it "right" now, than have to unpick it later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for a nice GWT3/J2CL ready widget lib, please take a look here: https://github.com/DominoKit/domino-ui.

You'll find a demo app here: https://demo.dominokit.org/home

Domino-ui is based on Elemento (https://github.com/hal/elemento) With Elemento you can create J2CL-ready widgets really easy.

Regarding your question about the modules:
We are currently working on making the GWT modules J2CL ready. A few of them are already released to Maven Central as rc1. For more informations take a look here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15WXfiklnTeqjRLI8gKj5iyGk7iDhnuQHGcpYJgpNlmQ/edit#gid=0

and here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b1D9fEqRh5lZ8cqMJtYoc_25rfTRvsuJkTtS2vjgi3o/edit#gid=0

Our goal is to make the migration as easy as possible. Mostly just replacing `com.google.gwt` with `org.gwtproject` and `GWT.create` statements with something like `new ...Impl`. The new modules will work with GWT 2 & GWT 3/J2CL. At the moment a real drawback is, that only a few modules have made it's way to Maven Central. I would suggest to stay with the old modules and wait until the new modules are available in Maven Central.

There are two Gitter rooms that might be of interest you you:

- https://gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt
- https://gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt-modules

Comment: Thanks for pointing me at Domino. It looks amazing! I think I asked the wrong question by slanting it towards modules. My question is really whether **Resources, GSS and I18N** support will be available in the GWT3 compiler. These aren't just client-side modules that can be ported to JsInterop, but are extra services that the GWT compiler currently offers.

Comment: Migration of resources (https://github.com/treblereel/gwt-resources) and i18n (https://github.com/vegegoku/gwt-i18n-apt) is in progress, but not ready to use, I think. In my opinion, you can use both and migrate later. Not sure about GSS

Comment: Not quite ready to use, but the API will be similar that updating your existing code should be straightforward.